# What is the difference between Document and document?

Tags: javascript

Refer link [Document.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) where it says:

> Document.children: Returns the child elements of the current document.

**and**

[document.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/children) page where the code example is given as `document.children;`

So why the minor difference between the code **syntax** between Caps D in `Document.children` compared to small case **d** in `document.children`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Document (with a capital "D") refers to the interface.
- document (with a lower-case "d") refers to the object that implements
  the interface.

So, in code, you'd use `document`.

If you are unfamiliar with "interface" vs. "implementation", you can think of it like this...

A Honda Civic and a Lamborghini both can have a manual transmission "interface", but the way that this interface is implemented in each vehicle "object" may differ.  So the interface is "manual transmission", but the objects that implement that interface are "Honda Civic" and "Lamborghini".

In the case of the Document Object Model, the "document" object implements the "Document" interface.

Answer (score 1):

```
> document instanceof Document
// true
> document.test
// undefined
> Document.propotype.test = 'test'
> document.test
// test
```

So `document` is not equal to `Document`

document (or window.document) is a reference to the document contained in the window.

Document is the DOM interface to the document, which is exposed on the global object.